# "Unable to locate element" or "TimeoutException" errors when trying to click on a button with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to click on "Show more" under the description of this [listing](https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/50293998?adults=1&children=0&infants=0&check_in=2022-06-21&check_out=2022-06-28&federated_search_id=9f8562f3-653a-45b7-b6bd-218379131b41&source_impression_id=p3_1653519105_nsyk%2Fkxp2MNH1yam) by using selenium (I am trying to collect data of multiple listings).

[This is what the HTML looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWr7C.png)

```
<button type="button" class="b1k5q1b3 v19vkvko dir dir-ltr">...</button>
```

I have tried using By.CLASS_NAME method but I get an error saying unable to locate element:

```
url = "https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/50293998?adults=1&children=0&infants=0&check_in=2022-06-21&check_out=2022-06-28&federated_search_id=9f8562f3-653a-45b7-b6bd-218379131b41&source_impression_id=p3_1653519105_nsyk%2Fkxp2MNH1yam"

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver_path = "C:/Users/parkj/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = Service(driver_path))
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "b1k5q1b3 v19vkvko dir dir-ltr")
button.click()
```

[This is what the error looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWfOA.png)

If I use By.CSS_SELECTOR, I get a [TimeoutException error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSwGq.png):

```
driver_path = "C:/Users/parkj/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = Service(driver_path))
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "b1k5q1b3 v19vkvko dir dir-ltr")))
```

I still get a Timeout error even if I make the driver wait longer.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from typing import Union

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, WebDriverException


def get_element(driver, by: By, identifier: str, timeout: int) -> Union[WebElement, None]:
    try:
        return WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((by, identifier))
        )
    except (WebDriverException, NoSuchElementException):
        return None

driver = WebDriver(service = Service("path_to_driver"))

# The way to do it using class_name
button = get_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "b1k5q1b3 v19vkvko dir dir-ltr", 180)

# If you want to select by css
button = get_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".b1k5q1b3 .v19vkvko .dir .dir-ltr", 180)
```

Personally I always use this function when working with Selenium. When selecting by classes you have to use `By.CLASS_NAME`, if you want to use `CSS_SELCTOR` you must put a `.` in front of the class names.

**TLDR**: you are missing a `.`